# Windows Store App MediaCapture Simulator Crash

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I am using the following function in my app to capture a photo using MediaCapture class and copy it to clipboard:

```
        async private void UseCamera()
        {
        var _ImageFormat = ImageEncodingProperties.CreatePng();
        var _fileStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();

        try
        {
            await _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync();
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(e.Message).ShowAsync();
        }

        try
        {
            await _mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(_ImageFormat, _fileStream);
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(e.Message).ShowAsync();
        }

        var _streamRef = Windows.Storage.Streams.RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromStream(_fileStream);
        _dataPackage.SetBitmap(_streamRef);


        Clipboard.SetContent(_dataPackage);
        Clipboard.Flush();

    }
```

The app is running fine on my local machine. But when I try to run it on simulator, i am given this error:

"An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in SensorGridCamera.exe but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"

Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: Have you tried running your application as Admin?

Comment: try to remove `MessageDialog` in code temporary and see the result because some time it throws `UnauthorizedAccessException`. Don't use `async void` in method, use `async Task`

Comment: Middas- how to run as admin in simulator?

Comment: Xyroid - i reduced code to just initialization of mediacapture object and await _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(); looks like this line has some issues.. will try the task method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I found this thing, which worked for me:

The trick was to pass a MediaCaptureInitializationSettings object in the await _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(); method as an argument and before you do that, set the object's PhotoCaptureSource property to VideoPreview and voila!

```
            MediaCaptureInitializationSettings _cameraSettings1 = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings();
            _cameraSettings1.PhotoCaptureSource = PhotoCaptureSource.VideoPreview;
            await _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(_cameraSettings1);
```

Hope it helps.
Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it's a permissions issue, running as Admin should fix it.  Add an Application Manifest to your project.  Then change `<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />` to `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />`  This will force your application to request to be run as Admin when it's run.

Comment: looks like the problem is with this piece of code:

await _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync();

This should launch a 'request permission to use camera and mic' box upon being triggered.
It is doing that fine when I debug the code in LocalMachine, but throwing error in Simulator..